# SQL query syntax with multiple SUM

Tags: sql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name,
    SUM(tziros_imeras) AS tziros_imeras,
    SUM(tziros_imeras_X_fpa) AS tziros_imeras_X_fpa,
    SUM(polithenta_karotsia) AS polithenta_karotsia,
    SUM(polithenta_kathismata) AS polithenta_kathismata,
    SUM(ask_for_furni) AS ask_for_furni,
    SUM(ask_for_karotsi) AS ask_for_karotsi,
    SUM(ask_for_kathisma) AS ask_for_kathisma,
    SUM(furni_reservation) AS furni_reservation,
    SUM(tziros_imeras) AS tziros_imeras
FROM
    dbo.Reports,
    dbo.Stores
WHERE
    dbo.Reports.Store_id = dbo.Stores.Store_id
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name ASC
```

This query works perfect and he does what I am really needed to do (I am getting the desired results in the loop).

My problem is that I need one more info to be included in my results. I want the info of the column `nomisma` from the table `Nomismata`.

The tables that involved to do that are the following 2: `Stores` & `Nomismata` and they have the following structure:

- `Stores` (Store_id, fpa_id, nomisma_id, Store_Name, Store_password)
- `Nomismata` (nomisma_id, nomisma)

Is there any possible way to have the `nomisma` info to be included correctly in my query??

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean with _included correctly_?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then simplify your question.

Comment: @jarlh I need something like that:
SELECT * FROM dbo. Nomismata, dbo.Stores WHERE dbo. Nomismata. nomisma_id = dbo. Stores. nomisma_id AND dbo.Stores. Store_Name equal with the Store_Name of my posted query.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. (With at least one dbo.Stores.Store_Name value having two different nomisma values.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I recommend to use "JOIN" (either INNER, LEFT, RIGHT ... as you need) within the "FROM" clause from:

```
FROM
    dbo.Reports,
    dbo.Stores
WHERE
    dbo.Reports.Store_id = dbo.Stores.Store_id
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name ASC
```

to

```
FROM
    dbo.Reports  
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Stores ON dbo.Reports.Store_id = dbo.Stores.Store_id
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name ASC
```

... now, including your new table:

```
SELECT
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name, 
    Nomismata.nomisma,
    SUM(tziros_imeras) AS tziros_imeras,
    SUM(tziros_imeras_X_fpa) AS tziros_imeras_X_fpa,
    SUM(polithenta_karotsia) AS polithenta_karotsia,
    SUM(polithenta_kathismata) AS polithenta_kathismata,
    SUM(ask_for_furni) AS ask_for_furni,
    SUM(ask_for_karotsi) AS ask_for_karotsi,
    SUM(ask_for_kathisma) AS ask_for_kathisma,
    SUM(furni_reservation) AS furni_reservation,
    SUM(tziros_imeras) AS tziros_imeras
FROM    
    dbo.Reports  
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Stores ON dbo.Reports.Store_id = dbo.Stores.Store_id
INNER JOIN 
    Nomismata ON dbo.Stores.nomisma_id = Nomismata.nomisma_id
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name, Nomismata.nomisma
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Stores.Store_Name ASC
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Works perfect! Now I am having the correct nomisma for each store! Many thanks for that and also for your helpful advice regarding the use of JOIN.

Comment: And you get the expected result even if a store has several different nomisma values?

Comment: Then it's fine!

Comment: @jarlh - Thank you jarlh!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a join with the `Nomismata` table(with `Stores` table) on `nomisma_id` column. Add the `nomisma` column in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses. Since the joining column is `nomisma_id`, I am assuming `nomisma` is a dimension and not a numeric column to be summed.

Also added `JOIN` instead of cross joins that you had. This would make the query more efficient.

```
SELECT
dbo.Stores.Store_Name, dbo.Nomismata.nomisma,
SUM(tziros_imeras) AS tziros_imeras,
SUM(tziros_imeras_X_fpa) AS tziros_imeras_X_fpa,
SUM(polithenta_karotsia) AS polithenta_karotsia,
SUM(polithenta_kathismata) AS polithenta_kathismata,
SUM(ask_for_furni) AS ask_for_furni,
SUM(ask_for_karotsi) AS ask_for_karotsi,
SUM(ask_for_kathisma) AS ask_for_kathisma,
SUM(furni_reservation) AS furni_reservation,
SUM(tziros_imeras) AS tziros_imeras
FROM
dbo.Reports 
JOIN dbo.Stores ON dbo.Reports.Store_id = dbo.Stores.Store_id
JOIN dbo.Nomismata ON dbo.Nomismata.nomisma_id = dbo.Stores.nomisma_id
GROUP BY dbo.Stores.Store_Name, dbo.Nomismata.nomisma
ORDER BY dbo.Stores.Store_Name ASC;
```

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Answer (score 0):

join Nomismata to the existing query

SELECT
    Stores.Store_Name,
 
    Nomismata.nomisma,
    SUM(tziros_imeras) AS tziros_imeras,
    SUM(tziros_imeras_X_fpa) AS tziros_imeras_X_fpa,
    SUM(polithenta_karotsia) AS polithenta_karotsia,
    SUM(polithenta_kathismata) AS polithenta_kathismata,
    SUM(ask_for_furni) AS ask_for_furni,
    SUM(ask_for_karotsi) AS ask_for_karotsi,
    SUM(ask_for_kathisma) AS ask_for_kathisma,
    SUM(furni_reservation) AS furni_reservation,
    SUM(tziros_imeras) AS tziros_imeras
FROM dbo.Reports Reports 
INNER JOIN dbo.Stores Stores 
ON Reports.Store_id = Stores.Store_id
JOIN dbo.Nomismata Nomismata 
ON Nomismata.nomisma_id = Stores.nomisma_id
GROUP BY Stores.Store_Name, 
    Nomismata.nomisma
ORDER BY Stores.Store_Name